# Vintage BMX bike

Tags: serial-number

I have my old bmx bike from when I was a kid, I’m trying to do some research to find out the make and model. I got the bike second hand and it had been stripped and repainted, the serial number is on the bottom bracket.
From what I can tell the paint was originally white, I got this bike in the early 90’s, so if I had to guess it would be from the 70’s or 80’s.

RD 04611

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.[image][image][image][image]

Comment: Unless you know the brand already, the serial number is no help at all.  You might get some answers, if you post a couple of clear and well-lit photos of the bike - one from the right-hand side showing the whole thing, and a second showing a close up of some unique or distinctive part.

Comment: That bike wasn't stripped - the red paint is clearly still there.  See if you can peel off the black, or possibly a gentle warming with a hot air gun might be enough to drop the top layer of paint.  There may be info under the black paint.   ALSO, the left-side chainstay has an interesting bracket, possibly to hold the reaction arm of a coaster brake or a gearbox.   The web under the headtube looks quite distinctive.    Rust on the BB says its a steel frame.

Comment: I painted the bike black when I was a kid, it was pink when I was given the bike. The woman that gave me the bike told me her son had painted the bike multiple times.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a [1986 Redline RL-20a](https://bmxmuseum.com/bikes/redline/61628) with a frame that matches closely. Both the 1986 and 1987 (there are no RL-20a bikes in BMX Museum after 1987)

[1986 Redline catalogue](https://issuu.com/frogbmx/docs/redline-1986) page 16-17 shows that the 20a frame is the one with the brake strap anchor.

[image]

It has the correct
- gusset
- off center bottom bracket down tube location
- brake strap anchor
- rear drop out shape, and general frame tube shapes.

Those handlebars did not come with that bike - no idea what they are.

Comment: I think you nailed it! The large oval bottom tube, and bracket. The brake strap anchor, everything is identical. Thank you so much for your research. The handle bars I found out last night are CW, they had to be swapped out by the previous owner. 
I also have a 84 redline 500a my son and I just finished rebuilding, now we can build this one knowing the correct parts to get. Thanks again!